# Sort the contained objects in an Array by the last name, first name - descending

Tags: javascript

Given the following Array, how do we write code that sorts the contained objects by the last name, first name descending?

```
[
{key: 1, firstName: "George", lastName: "Jones"},
{key: 1, firstName: "Alison", lastName: "Clarke"},
{key: 1, firstName: "Ben", lastName: "Smith"},
{key: 1, firstName: "Xavier", lastName: "Clark"},
{key: 1, firstName: "Harold", lastName: "Timmins"}
]
```

I don't know how to proceed on this and I thought you guys might help.

Thanks

Comment: This looks more like JavaScript to me...

Comment: Please, Java **is not** JavaScript. Edit your question accordingly to get the desired answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
myarray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.lastName.localeCompare(a.lastName) ||
           b.firstName.localeCompare(a.firstName)
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/nMs67/

Comment: upvoted your answer but this also works (for those who like more verbose code):
`myarray.sort(function (a, b) {
  var fullNameA = a.lastName + ' ' + a.firstName;
  var fullNameB = b.lastName + ' ' + b.firstName;

  if (fullNameA > fullNameB) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (fullNameA < fullNameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
`}

Answer (score 1):

Write your own `Comparator` that compares the objects using the logic you wrote above, and call the [two parameters version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) of `Arrays.sort` with it.

This is largely the same in Java or JavaScript, except that in Java, the `Comparator` needs to be an object of a class implementing the `Comparator` interface, while in JavaScript just a function would be enough. This somewhat highlights JavaScript's functional aspect and Java's Object oriented nature.